# js to load correct css

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a responsive site.  I know I'm supposed to work from smallest to largest, so mobile to tablet to desktop.  But I don't want the desktop images downloading on the mobile to save bandwidth and time.  I also know that the browser doesn't send info about itself to the server so I can't use php.

In short, I need a way to use js to determine which css file to load before it loads.  is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a media query on the link-tag including the stylesheet to let the browser sort it all out itself. No need for JS for anything here.

[Example code here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html).

Comment: will desktop images get downloaded on mobile if we use inline media queries in a single file?

Comment: As I understand, media queries do not prevent imgs from being downloaded.  So the mobile will still download the desktop images.  This is what I need to prevent

Comment: @sabithpocker no, only triggered rules are processed, and if need be referenced assets downloaded.

Comment: @user1416301 media queries will not stop *inline* images from being loaded, but neither will Javascript. If you desperately need to stop the mobile clients from downloading those you need to feed them a different HTML source, for example by using WURFL on the server end to determine the client browser type.

Comment: I can change the source of inline images after the page loads.  which essentially prevents all but the first one from download.  which I set as default to the mobile

Comment: You would think this works, but it doesn't.  The browser requests *all* style sheets, even if it doesn't meet the conditions of the media query.  It just doesn't *apply* the styles unless they fit the criteria of the media query.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can really do to prevent embedded images from being downloaded with JavaScript.  *Some* of the images will begin downloading before you can modify the DOM.

If the concern is for background images, then the browser only requests the image if it needs.  In the following CSS example, only the small.gif is requested by narrow devices and only big.gif is requested by wide devices.

```
.foo {
    background: url(small.gif);
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .foo {
        background: url(big.gif);
    }
}
```

See more information about background images and mobile devices:  http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

It is a common misconception that using media queries in the `<link />` element will prevent the stylesheets from downloading if the device doesn't need them, but this is false.  The browser requests all CSS files, including alternates, in case the browser has a need for them later.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/responsive.css" media="screen" title="Responsive" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 800px)" title="Mobile" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/desktop.css" media="(min-width: 801px)" title="Desktop" />
```

You can see from the access logs from 2 different devices that all 3 style sheets are requested.

Opera Mobile emulator

```
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - - "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /js/menu.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /photo_420x315.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/81_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2931 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /js/modernizr/2.6.1.custom-input.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /js/address_picker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /placeholders/728x90_banner.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/60_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2818 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/119_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3223 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /css/desktop.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /css/mobile.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/76_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2907 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/loader.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /css/mobile.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:53 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/details/logifill-details-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:54 -0400] "GET /css/desktop.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:54 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:54 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/119_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3223 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - - "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:26:55 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/103_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3368 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows; Opera Mobi/35779; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00"
```

Android emulator

```
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:26 -0400] "GET /css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:26 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/loader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:26 -0400] "GET /js/address_picker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:26 -0400] "GET /js/modernizr/2.6.1.custom-input.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:26 -0400] "GET /js/menu.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/datetime-local/datetime-local-polyfill.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/datetime-local/datetime-local-polyfill.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /js/polyfills/details/logifill-details-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /photo_420x315.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 3115 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/81_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2931 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /placeholders/728x90_banner.png HTTP/1.1" 200 24434 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/103_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3368 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/60_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2818 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:28 -0400] "GET /uploads/photos/76_230x200.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2907 "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:29 -0400] "GET /css/mobile.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:34 -0400] "GET /apple-touch-icon-72x72.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1262 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
10.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2013:14:29:35 -0400] "GET /css/desktop.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://10.0.0.102:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; sdk Build/MASTER) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

Comment: well, as long as the mobile doesn't download the bg imgs for the desktop, I don't suppose I care if it downloads the css file.  that's pretty small

Answer (score 0):

Dont use js for that, you can do something like this directly in your html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="/css/widescreen.css">
```

so, you only load the "widescreen" css in big screens.

Comment: Niels posted the same answer.

Comment: right, I forgot about this